# The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.1.2' was not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I create my application and it successfully creates the docker container. When I try and run it

```
docker run -it --name myapp myapp:latest
```

I get the following error:

```
The specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.All', version '2.1.2' was not found.
...
- The following versions are installed:
      2.1.1 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
```

When I log into the container, I can see that, in the `/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` folder, there is one subfolder called `2.1.2`.

I can't figure out why it's saying that 2.1.1 is installed and 2.1.2 is not??

The following is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.400-sdk-stretch AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.400-sdk-stretch AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY source/application/MyApp/MyApp.csproj source/application/MyApp/
COPY source/application/MyApp.DependentProject/MyApp.DependentProject.csproj source/application/MyApp/
RUN dotnet restore source/application/MyApp/MyApp.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/source/application/MyApp
RUN dotnet build MyApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```

Comment: What docker container image are you using?

Comment: I've been trying various ones listed https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/
Right now I am using microsoft/dotnet:2.1.400-sdk-stretch as Base.

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant, but Docker Support was added after the fact, not in the project template when the project was first created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try changing:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.400-sdk-stretch AS base
```

to

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet AS base
```

or

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1.2-sdk AS base
```

See the [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/) and [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/docker-basics-dotnet-core) on dotnet core and docker for further examples

Comment: FROM microsoft/dotnet AS base
creates the same result, saying 2.1.1 is installed but 2.1.2 is not.

Comment: The docker docs have this step in there example # Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetapp.dll"]